# Same name table of different contracts got merged

Tags: eosjs, multi-index, table

I wrote a contract, suppose `C` defining the multi-index table `T`. Table struct has two parameter suppose `x` and `y`. `x` was the primary key. I made some entries in `T` and when i tried to access it back, I came to know that table is not added in abi so i cannot access the table data using `eos.getTableRows()`.Call it deployment A.
I redeployed the contract keeping the contract name `C`, from same account `C` and making `y` the primary key and everything else just same(Table `T`). Again i made some entries.Call it deployment B.

Now when I access the table, I get all the entries of deployment A & B.

- Is it normal? If yes, on which parameter(`x` or `y`), lower & upper_bound will work? As they work on primary key and here we are getting a merged table with different primary key in each deployment.
- How can I get the separate data of both the
  deployments? I mean what parameters contributed in their merging contract name, account name or table name?

Comment: If anything needs further explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this description i can say that at the time of deployment called A you have not added that table abi that's why you are not able to call `getTableRows()` but actually the table actions have executed and made entries on table and occupied RAM also.Now, what happens when you redeployed the same contract with same account and made some changes but that RAM is still occupied with your old table entries and when you enter new entries that also added on table and shows you both data.You are facing this because that old data was not erased from RAM.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. Can you please visit the two queries in the question and can add information regarding them?

Comment: as i need more explanation on first one but i can say that for second query that it can be done now only by erasing old entries and made new entries on behalf of them.the parameters contributed in merging is account name.

Comment: So if with this account, i deploy any other contract with any xyz name but same table name, they will get merged?

Comment: Yes exactly it will merged because you can have only one contract per account

Comment: ok, i got it. I update the first question, is it clear to you now?

Comment: In lower & upper_bound will not work because as u redeploy contract you have only one primary key forgot that old one.